# Pushing elements from a 2d to 1d vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I am trying to push elements from a 2d integer matrix(created using vector of vectors) into a 1d  integer vecto.While trying to push back if I do:

```
 //declarations
 //vector<vector<int>>nums
 //vector<int>ans;int a
 for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++)
    { 
        for(int j=0;j<nums[i].size();j++)
        {        
                arr.push_back(nums[i,j]);
        }
    }
```

I am getting an error as no matching function call.
However if I do this:

```
 for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++)
    { 
        for(int j=0;j<nums[i].size();j++)
        {       a=nums[i,j]; 
                arr.push_back(a);    
        }
    }
```

It works.
I understand that ,nums[][] is getting read as a vector,but shouldn't nums[i][j] which is an integer be read as it is and not raise an error. Can somebody explain the difference in both the cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question is not as simple as it seems. Let me break it down for you:

- Be careful when using commas in your code! C++ has its own [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) rules, which means that `i,j` gets evaluated to `j`, so `nums[i,j]` is equal to `nums[j]`
- The operator `[]` on `vector<vector<int>>` returns an instance of the element type of this vector, which is `vector<int>`. Accessing an element of this inner vector can be done by using the `[]` operator again.
  Thus If you want to access a single element in the 2d vector, you first
  have to select the outer vector and then its inner element, i.e.
  `nums[i][j]`.
  **C++ has no special syntax for accessing
  multi-dimensional arrays/vectors!**

Comment: The first point is very informative,something I didn't know  about !

Answer (score 4):

The syntax for indexing into a 2 dimensional matrix is `nums[i][j]` and not `nums[i,j]`

This is because of how `operator[]` overloading works for a `std::vector`.  You can supply a single integer as an argument and not a pair, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at

The expression `nums[i][j]` first evaluates as `((nums[i])[j])` where the inner parentheses evaluates to a reference to the `i`th element in `nums`, which is of type `vector<int>`.  And then the second `[j]` evaluates to a reference to an element of the inner vector, i.e. of type, (possibly const qualified) `int&`

Comment: Minor disagreement on that last paragraph. It's not because of how `[]` works, it's because `vector` is always 1 dimensional. `vector<vector<int>>nums` is a `vector` of `vector`s. The first `[]` gets the appropriate inner `vector` and the second gets the `int` from that inner `vector`.

Comment: @user4581301 doesn't that count as *how `operator[]` overloading works for a `std::vector`*?